# Hide button in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

when i hide a button in rails then other buttons move to that place i want to place the button in a parallel line and the place of other buttons should be clear if those are not visible to that case.... my code is as following:

```
<div class=" list_el">
              <span class="pull-right" style="text-align:right">
              <%if accountant?%>
                <%= link_to_if(!crm_donation["received"],  "Approved", crm_donations_path(:id => crm_donation["id"]), :class => "label label-success") if !crm_donation["received"]%>
              <%end%>

              <%= link_to "rollback", edit_crm_donation_rollback_path(crm_donation["id"]), :class => 'label label-info'  if supervisor? && crm_donation["rollback_id"].blank?%>

              <%= link_to "delete",  crm_donation_path(crm_donation["id"]), :class => 'label label-important1', method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } if accountant? && !crm_donation["received"]%>

              <%= link_to "details", crm_donation_path(crm_donation["id"]), :class => 'label label-success' %>


              <%if !accountant?%>
                <%= link_to "pdf", "/letter/#{crm_donation["id"]}.pdf", :class => "label label-info1", :target=>"_blank"%>

                <%if crm_donation["email_sent"]%>
                  <%=link_to_if(crm_donation["received"], "email", donation_email_sent_path(crm_donation["email_sent"]), :class=>"label label-emails") { label_tag( "email" , "email",:class => "label") }%>

                <%else%>
                  <%if !crm_donation["rollback_id"]%> 
                    <%=link_to_if(crm_donation["received"], "email", new_donation_email_sent_path(:donation_id => crm_donation["id"]), :class=>"label label-emailf") { label_tag( "email" , "email",:class => "label") } %>
                  <%end%>  

                <%end%>
              <%end%>

            </span>
            </div>
```

button positions are like this:

```
                 details | pdf
rollback | details | pdf | email
```

and i want to do like this:

```
           details | pdf
rollback | details | pdf | email
```

Comment: use seperate div tags for each button and required positioning for those div tags

Comment: can you please chnage the code and place divs as they are to be there for align?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all remove inline styling and place all the styling in asset pipeline. Create divs for each button and then use css positioning to align them properly. If you are hiding some of the buttons and it's changing your button's alignment(as you mentioned in your question) then use visibility: hidden rather then display: none. As when you do visibility: hidden to a particular element, that element is still present but it's hidden